# Print UTF-8 option value in php

Tags: php, utf-8

So I have this HTML:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="result.php" target="_blank">
  <select name="date-shamsi-week-day">
    <option value="شنبه" selected>شنبه</option>
    <option value="یکشنبه" title="something">یکشنبه</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

and I want to print it in a variable in another file like this:

```
<?php 
  $dateshamsiweekday = $_POST['date-shamsi-week-day'];
  echo $dateshamsiweekday;
?>
```

it works just fine but as you can see I need to use UTF-8 (persian characters) and it doesn't echo anything when looking at the output.

ٍEDIT: it's a shame but since it's my first day learning php I had a syntax error because I used **،** after my variable name and it got nothing to do with UTF-8 Characters.

Comment: Did you try setting the charset in the content type? `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8')`

Comment: I have <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> in the head of both files

Comment: So is the reply actually missing those characters or is the browser just not displaying them?

Comment: it actually doesnt get printed in the page

Comment: I know, but if you inspect the actual HTTP reply outside of the browser, are the characters there or not?

Answer (score 1):

Your current PHP syntax is wrong. Try changing it to this:

```
<?php 
    $dateshamsiweekday = $_POST['date-shamsi-week-day'];
    echo '<span>'.$dateshamsiweekday.'</span>';
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, well actually its a whole HTML page getting echo with that so I tried to minimize it and paste that part, there's not anything wrong with the result, the thing is if I use UTF-8 as value it wont echo, otherwise it works just fine

Answer (score 1):

The `<span>` tags need to be outside the PHP code block; they're not PHP, but HTML.

```
<?php 
  $dateshamsiweekday = $_POST['date-shamsi-week-day'];
?><span><?= $dateshamsiweekday ?></span>
```

or, if you're using PHP before 5.4.0 and don't have `short_open_tags` enabled,

```
<?php 
  $dateshamsiweekday = $_POST['date-shamsi-week-day'];
?><span><?php echo $dateshamsiweekday ?></span>
```

Either way, you must then open up another `<?php` if you want more code after that.

Comment: well I just edited the question, it's not about any html tags, even without any html tags, I cant echo any UTF8 characters as value for options, thats my issue

Answer (score -2):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"/> 
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $date_day= $_POST['date-shamsi-week-day'];
    echo $date_day;
}
?> 

<form  method="post" action="">
  <select name="date-shamsi-week-day">
    <option value="&#1588;&#1606;&#1576;&#1607;" selected>&#1588;&#1606;&#1576;&#1607;</option>
    <option value="&#1740;&#1705;&#1588;&#1606;&#1576;&#1607;" title="something">&#1740;&#1705;&#1588;&#1606;&#1576;&#1607;</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but 2 questions:
1. how you changed the characters to this things? because there are more of them I need to convert?
2. it doesnt actually solved the problem, what's wrong with the code for not printing UTF-8 characters‌?

Comment: 1. Western European encoding. You can convert it using dreamwaver.

Comment: With `accept-charset="utf-8"` you shouldn't have to entity-encode aything in the form...